# Is Cu stable as Cu(H2O)2+ for determination on MP-AES?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, analytical-chemistry, metal

I have an unknown sample of mineral which I need to dissolve in nitric acid. I need to analyze $\ce{Cu}$ from it on MP-AES. Do I need to add $\pu{1ml}$ of $\ce{HCl}$ to stabilize $\ce{Cu}$, or it is enough just $\ce{HNO3}$?

Answer (score 1):

[This procedure from an MP-AES manufacturer](http://www.agilent.com/cs/library/applications/5991-5991EN_mp-aes_4200_soils_inert_torch.pdf) features copper analysis (among other elements) without the use if hydrochloric acid.  Hydrogen peroxide is used in this procedure but would not affect the extraction of copper.  A copper standard is also available in "5% nitric acid" solution from [the same company](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G4VPTAE).

So the people who are selling this technology do not believe hydrochloric acid is needed for copper analysis, you can try nitric acid alone if this gets your sample to dissolve.